# Recharts: How to disable tooltip content from moving with mouse cursor

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Is there a way to stop the content of the tooltip from following the mouse pointer?

[image]

As you can see in the image, the content is beneath the pointer. If the pointer goes any lower, the content goes to the top of the chart. Is there a way to stop this behavior and keep the content at the top of the bar where the pointer is hovered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `position` prop for the tooltip, eg

```
<Tooltip position={{ x: 100, y: 140 }}/>
```

You can check out more about this in the [Recharts docs](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/Tooltip#position)

**Edit:**

If you need to render the tooltip above the hovered bar, as far as I see in the docs there is no out of the box solution. However you can manage this manually:

- grab the hovered bar's position with the `onMouseEnter` method of the `<Bar>`
- put that value (with the offset of the tooltip) into a state
- update the `<Tooltip>`'s position based on the new state

```
const App = () => {
  const [tooltipPosition, setTooltipPosition] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 })

  const onMouseEnter = (e) => {
    const tooltipHeight = 60 // you need to change this based on your tooltip
    setTooltipPosition({ x: e.x, y: e.y - tooltipHeight })
  }

  return (
    <BarChart
      width={500}
      height={300}
      data={data}>
      <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis />
      <Tooltip
        position={tooltipPosition}
        allowEscapeViewBox={{ y: true }}/>
      <Legend />
      <Bar dataKey="key" fill="#1DDDFF" onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}/>
    </BarChart>
  )
}
```

Comment: I've tried that, but the `position` prop causes the content to be displayed in the same place, regardless of where the pointer is currently hovering over. The content needs to be displayed adjacent to the bar section the pointer is hovering over.

Comment: @Echo, I've updated the answer based on this comment

Comment: Thanks for the edit, although, the solution requires the pointer to be directly over the bar itself to be repositioned, unlike the default behavior of the tooltip where even if the pointer is over the empty space above the bar, the tooltip still changes position. Do you know any property that customizes that?

Comment: Yes, for that behaviour you can use the `BarChart`'s `onMouseMove` prop. It returns an object which includes the active "bar area" where the mouse is located at. From this object you can either use the `activeLabel` or `activePayload` to grab the active bar's area and update the tooltip's position according to it!

Comment: @DanielSz I know it's been a while, but was wondering what you meant by "using `activeLabel` to grab the active bar's area? How would you get the new X/Y position for the new chart so it works the same as it currently does with your answer? (positioning at the top of the bar)

Comment: @trainoasis in the original answer, the event listener is bound to the `Bar` component. So, when you don't hover over exactly the bar in the graph (e.g., the cursor is above the bar), the `Tooltip`'s position doesn't update. If you need to update the `Tooltip`'s position for the entire bar area, you can use the `BarChart`'s `onMouseMove` function, which returns the cursor position (`chartX`, `chartY`) and also the value of the hovered data item in `activeLabel` which can be used for the `Tooltip`'s content

Comment: @DanielSz yes, I am aware of that, thanks. But the default `onMouseEnter` on the `Bar` returns X coordinate which matches the left START of the bar and Y which seems to match the top of the bar. I can't get to these same X/Y with `onMouseMove` for the current `activeTooltipIndex` can I ? The goal is to keep the tooltip position above the Bar that is being hovered, even if what is hovered is actually the area ABOVE the bar itself.